# Cumulative column based on the values of a calculated column

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

I am working on a SELECT:

```
SELECT  
    datein as 'Date In',      
    COUNT(lab) as 'Count of Jobs',    
    ROUND(COUNT(lab) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(lab)) OVER(),2) AS 'Percentage'   
    "CODE FOR CUMULATIVE PERCENTAGE"
FROM [DailyWIP].[dbo].[WIP_ETO] 
GROUP BY datein 
ORDER BY datein desc;
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Also, it would be good if you could provide sample data that correspond to your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT datein,      
       COUNT(lab) as job_count    
       ROUND(COUNT(lab) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(lab)) OVER (),2) AS Percentage  
       ROUND(SUM(COUNT(lab)) OVER (PARTITION BY datein DESC) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(lab)) OVER (), 2) AS Cumulative_Percentage  
FROM [DailyWIP].[dbo].[WIP_ETO] 
GROUP BY datein 
ORDER BY datein desc;
```

Comment: GREAT! I changed it a little to this:   ROUND(SUM(COUNT(lab)) OVER (ORDER BY datein DESC) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(lab)) OVER (),2) AS Cumulative_Percentage   and it worked as I needed, THANK YOU VERY MUCH